# Insert 0 or 1 into MySQL based on checkbox value

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I would like to insert the `"0"` or `"1"` into mysql database by using php checkbox. However, it is unable to modify or insert on mysql database.

My coding `edit.php`:

```
<?php 
switch($_GET['action']) {
  case "Modify":
  /*************************** case "modify" **********************/
    $colname_RsStaff = "1";
    if (isset($_GET['staffid'])) {
      $colname_RsStaff = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
                         ? $_GET['staffid'] : addslashes($_GET['staffid']);
    }
    mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
    $query_RsStaff = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_staff`
                      WHERE `tbl_staff`.`staffid` = '".$_GET['staffid']."'";
    $RsStaff = mysql_query($query_RsStaff, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_RsStaff = mysql_fetch_assoc($RsStaff);
    $totalRows_RsStaff = mysql_num_rows($RsStaff);

    $subagent = $row_RsStaff['subagent'];
    $subum = $row_RsStaff['subum'];
    $subssm = $row_RsStaff['subssm'];
    $subtutor = $row_RsStaff['subtutor'];
    break;

  /* ****************Add**************** */
  default:
    $subagent = "";
    $subum = "";
    $subssm = "";
    $subtutor = "";
    break;
}
?> 

<form name="staff" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="commit.php?action=<?php echo $_GET['action'] ?>">
   <tr>
      <td height="12" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><h5>&nbsp;</h5></td>
      <td height="12" align="left" bgcolor="#dfdfdf">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="subagent[]" value="<?php echo $subagent; ?>" />&nbsp;Agent&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="subum[]" value="<?php echo $subum; ?>" />&nbsp;UM&nbsp;</td>
      <td rowspan="2" align="left" bgcolor="#dfdfdf">
      <h6>&nbsp;* Selected one or more</h6></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="12" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><h5>&nbsp;</h5></td>
      <td height="12" align="left" bgcolor="#dfdfdf">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="subssm[]" value="<?php echo $subssm; ?>" />&nbsp;SSM&nbsp;&nbsp;  <input type="checkbox" name="subtutor[]" value="<?php echo $subtutor; ?>" />&nbsp;Tutor&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="<?php echo $_GET['action'] ?>" />
```

Posting to `commit.php`

```
    $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
     $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
       }

    switch ($_GET['action']) {
    case "Create":
$staffid = $_POST['staffid'];

     mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
     $result ="SELECT * FROM tbl_staff WHERE staffid = '".$_POST['staffid']."'";
      $Staff = mysql_query($result, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
     $totalRows_Staff = mysql_num_rows($Staff);

     $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_staff (subagent, subum, subssm, subtutor) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                     GetSQLValueString($_POST['subagent'], "text"),
                 GetSQLValueString($_POST['subum'], "text"),
                         GetSQLValueString($_POST['subssm'], "text"),
                 GetSQLValueString($_POST['subtutor'], "text"),

                     mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
                     $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
                  }
                 $insertGoTo = "tr_staff.php";
          if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
          $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
          $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
           }
          header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
          }
      break;
     /************************* update *************************/
     case "Modify":

    $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE tbl_staff SET subagent=%s, subum=%s, subssm=%s, subtutor=%s WHERE staffid=%s",
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['subagent'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['subum'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['subssm'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['subtutor'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['staffid'], "int"));

             mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
             $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

          $insertGoTo = "tr_staff.php";
             if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
             $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
             $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
           }
          header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
          //}
           break;
          }
       ?>
```

Any advice would be super appreciated.

Comment: the form is posting and you're looking for $_GET variables.

Comment: It would also be nice to stop using mysql, and start using msqli or pdo..

Comment: Please avoid to use mysql to prevent SQL Injection..

Answer (score 0):

Try Code as below

**Errors**

- First you have used `POST` metod in form and get variable using `GET`
- You can try like below to get checkbox value

  `if ($subssm) {
      <input type='checkbox' name='subssm[]' value='1' />
  }else{
      <input type='checkbox' name='subssm[]' value='0' />
  }`

  ****PHP****

```
           <form name="staff" method="get" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="commit.php?action=<?php echo $_GET['action'] ?>">
           <tr>
              <td height="12" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><h5>&nbsp;</h5></td>
              <td height="12" align="left" bgcolor="#dfdfdf">&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="subagent[]" value="<?php echo $subagent; ?>" />&nbsp;Agent&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="subum[]" value="<?php echo $subum; ?>" />&nbsp;UM&nbsp;</td>
              <td rowspan="2" align="left" bgcolor="#dfdfdf">
              <h6>&nbsp;* Selected one or more</h6></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="12" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><h5>&nbsp;</h5></td>
              <td height="12" align="left" bgcolor="#dfdfdf">&nbsp;
    <?php
    if ($subssm) {
        <input type='checkbox' name='subssm[]' value='1' />
    }else{
        <input type='checkbox' name='subssm[]' value='0' />
    }
    ?>

    &nbsp;SSM&nbsp;&nbsp;  <input type="checkbox" name="subtutor[]" value="<?php echo $subtutor; ?>" />&nbsp;Tutor&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="<?php echo $_GET['action'] ?>" />
```

Comment: I tried to do your way. However, it is not working with this coding. the insert or modify to database which would be "Array". It is unable to insert "0" or "1".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little trick:
When working with checkboxes, just add a hidden field before the checkbox:

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkbox" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" />
```

Then you can access the value nicely with

```
<?php
   $checkboxValue = (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) ? intval($_POST['checkbox']) : 0; // returns 0 or 1
?>
```

and you save some lines of code.

**In your code, I'd replace**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subssm[]" value="<?php echo $subssm; ?>" />
```

with

```
<input type="hidden" name="subssm" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="subssm" <?php if($subssm == "1") echo "checked='checked'"; ?> value="1" />
```

Comment: if I follow this coding. Would you let me know how to modify the database with same page.

Comment: Thanks Christoph, it is successful to modify to mysql. Good! However, It can not display on same page from mysql database.

Comment: Hey Christoph, I would like to show up on same page from mysql database. For Example, I have 2 optional doing create information & modify information on edit.php only. I tried to follow your instruction coding. However, it would not display information when I selected the subssm box.

Comment: Finally, I have fixed this issue. Thanks a lot for any advice.