# Inserting checkbox value of 0 or 1 to database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I placed a new checkbox on an existing form on this website I am working on and I want it to update the database with a 0 or 1 based on if the checkbox has a check or not. I have been at this for some hours now to no avail.

Here is my input code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="propHosp" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="propHosp" <? if($propHosp == "1") echo "checked='checked'"; ?> value="1">
```

Here is the code I placed around the SQL Insert query code:

```
$hospValue = (isset($_GET['propHosp'])) ? intval($_GET['propHosp']) : 0; // returns 0 or 1
$sql = "INSERT INTO comments SET ";
$sql.= "propHosp = $hospValue";
--other sql lines omitted--
```

propHosp is the column and its default is 0. It should be a 1 if the checkbox is checked. It just keeps creating the new row with a 0 every time. I have tried changing $_GET to $_POST as well, no luck. Thanks for your help!

Comment: both your hidden input and checkbox bear the same name attribute; *why?*

Comment: I did that because I was referencing this article on here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373180/insert-0-or-1-into-mysql-based-on-checkbox-value

Comment: oh, I see. try checking for errors on both the PHP and MySQL side of things. Plus, your column's type could be at play also.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()`. But the latter is for `mysqli_` so I don't know which MySQL API you're using. Adjust accordingly.

Comment: Another thing. Make sure that short open tags are enabled on your system. If not, then you'll need to change `<?` to `<?php`. That could also be another issue here.

Comment: Fixed with this statement: `if(isset($_POST['propHosp']))
    {
     $hospValue = 1;
    }
    else
    {
     $hospValue = 0;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['propHosp']))
            {
                $hospValue = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                $hospValue = 0;
            }
```

Only one input as well, `<input type="checkbox" name="propHosp">`

Comment: another happy ending then

Comment: So it was all because of duplicate name, huh?